# Could a language with only fricatives at the end of words reasonably exist?

Tags: phonology, naturalism

There are several non-constructed languages, including English, in which almost all words end in consonants, but what about a language in which almost all words end in a certain type of consonant? In my case, I'm trying a synthetic language which relies on different types of fricatives at the end of words to show grammatical meaning. The language has several non-fricative consonants, but would it be realistic for those consonants not to form endings while the fricatives do?

Comment: ‘would it be realistic for those consonants to form endings while the fricatives do?’ — I have no idea what you’re asking here. Also, the obvious answer is: this conlang sounds like it isn’t intended to be naturalistic, so you can do what you like in it.

Comment: @bradrn I think they mean 'for those consonants NOT to form endings while the fricatives do'

Comment: @Richard That’s what I assume, but I’d appreciate confirmation from OP.

Comment: Yes, I mean what @Richard said.

Comment: @WhyIt In the future, please edit your question to fix the mistake. People who see your question shouldn't have to look to the comments for a clarification.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, of course, that's entirely possible!

See also [word-final voicing in Basque](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/335590616_Lenition_of_word-final_plosives_in_Basque), which is an example of a sound change that affects word-final consonants especially much. Conceivable, such could also lead to spirantization (plosive>fricative) word-finally. (And there are certainly more other ways such a trait could come to be)

Comment: In German you get "Auslautverhaertung", where voiced consonants become de-voiced (/d/ -> /t/, /g/ -> /k/)

Comment: @OliverMason True, it's a feature if other Germanic languages as well.

Comment: @OliverMason And Russian, and Sanskrit (there the change is shown in writing), and likely many others.

Comment: @Richard Very cool, thank's for the answer!

Comment: @WhyIt If you think the answer is sufficient, you can also accept it by clicking the checkmark!